# Looping over a single column in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table that looks like this and i want to know the number of entries that are registered over a six hour time period and display that period which has max number of entries.

```
Time
09:42:29
10:37:28
15:18:49
15:28:34
16:43:51
18:14:10
18:26:06
18:26:14
```

So for each element in Time column, i will include a 6 hour period starting from that element and count how many entries in that column will fall in that period. 
Ex 09:42:29 will have the end period has 15:42:29 and it should have count as 4 (09:42:29,10:37:28
15:18:49,15:28:34).

So do this for each element in Time Column and whichever element has max count, that will be the starting time of the period and display the start and end period accordingly.

Help me with writing a mysql query for this. Thank You!!!

Comment: [*Have you tried anything?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps

```
select
    T.TimeStart,
    T.TimeEnd,
    COUNT(*)
from (
    select
        T.Time TimeStart,
        date_add(T.Time,INTERVAL 6 HOUR) TimeEnd
    from TimeTable T
) T
inner join TimeTable T2 on
    T2.Time between T.TimeStart and T.TimeEnd
group by
    T.TimeStart,
    T.TimeEnd
```

---

The code below is for MSSQL but it works as expected and should give you some guidelines how the example above could be used

```
WITH TimeTable([Time]) AS (
select
CONVERT(DATETIME,a.a)
from (
values
('09:42:29'),
('10:37:28'),
('15:18:49'),
('15:28:34'),
('16:43:51'),
('18:14:10'),
('18:26:06'),
('18:26:14'))a(a)
)
select
    convert(time(7),T.TimeStart)TimeStart,
    convert(time(7),T.TimeEnd)TimeEnd,
    COUNT(*) [Ocorrences]
from (
    select
        T.Time TimeStart,
        DATEADD(HOUR,6,T.Time) TimeEnd
    from TimeTable T
) T
inner join TimeTable T2 on
    T2.Time between T.TimeStart and T.TimeEnd
group by
    T.TimeStart,
    T.TimeEnd
```

[image: Result]

Comment: @wittyenggs is the result in the my edited response your requirement?

Comment: @mxix....thanks for your answer....but the values may not be the ones in the database....then in that case the pre-defined values cannot be used....what is a substitute for it.